# Select statement returns no records when searching a field controlled by a value list

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to query an Access 2010 database using vb.net and am running into an issue where no results are being returned when searching a field that is backed by a value list.  Has anyone else experienced this issue?  Do I need to remove the value list for the query to work?  The command text and parameter are below.  The field [Cage Material] is backed by a value list in the database.

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [CAGE - BARREL] WHERE [Cage Material]=?"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[Cage Material]", Material)
```

Comment: What are the DB types...I am not sure I know what you mean by a 'value list' when it comes to a DB column

Comment: If you just use "SELECT * FROM [CAGE - BARREL]", what values do you get in the "[Cage Material]" column?  Does your `Material` variable contain one of those values?

Comment: The field data type is text.  Under the field properties, you can add a display control based on a text box, list box or combo box.  The source type would be table/query, value list, or field list.  The text string I was searching on is one of the values in the value list.  I just don't get why it would return 0 results when the data types are the same and the string is identical.  Making the same search in access gives a proper result, but the sql search through vb.net does not.